# How can i sync a picture from my desktop application to my webserver using Firebase?

Tags: asp.net, sql, web, firebase

I will like the following:
1. Is there an API for this?
2. If my app adds a picture, if this firebase is like dropbox (or better) can i read from the virtual folder to display the picture on the web?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase does not have a built-in way to sync filesystems. You could potentially use the Firebase REST API or the Node.js client to push images into Firebase though.

Once your data is in Firebase, it's easy to pull it down into a webpage using the javascript library. I'd recommend storing the image as a base64-encoded string and setting the dataURL on an image to display it.